# Installing global npm package (@vue/cli) in Node v10.9 also installs Node v10.8?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, nvm

This is weird, and I can't find a real answer for it - I suspect that its "supposed to do this" but it was strange. Here's what I did:

1. Completely cleaned node out of my system (OSX)
2. Reinstalled NVM and installed latest Node (10.9.0)
3. Verified that there were no other nodes being seen by NVM, verified all my paths, checked versions, etc. I was definitely in 10.9, and it was the only node installed.
4. I installed the vue client package: `npm install -g @vue/cli`
5. The package installs, no problems.
6. Typing `vue` and no binary is found.
7. If I run `nvm ls` I now have a v10.8.0, and when I explore that node's /bin folder, sure enough the vue binary was installed there, NOT in v10.9

I don't really have an issue with this, but I'd really like to know WHY this is happening, and what bad effects it might have later. I can easily move my default to 10.8, but I'd like to know why.

Is this something that the vue-cli package maintainers do?  Is it because its a scoped npm package? Or something else entirely?

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out. Leaving instructions for anyone else who might come along:

I ran `npm config list` and to my surprise found out that there was a .nvmrc file in my home folder that was overriding the "prefix" variable, pointing me to 10.8 instead of 10.9.

Deleted that file, and all is well. Sheesh.